# XML CDATA not working

Tags: xml, cdata

I'm using CDATA in XML
but I have a trouble using it, please help.

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../CSS/XML_Archive.css" ?>

<hqtunes>
  <contents>
    <key><![CDATA[<a href="#">Link</a>]]></key>
  </contents>
</hqtunes>
```

When I run this XML in Chrome and in Internet Explorer, it show me :

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

It not shows me as

```
Link
```

What is wrong this code ? How can I format CDATA ?

**Edit :** Here is my XML : http://hqtunes.com/hqtunes.xml 
All HTML tags are seen at my PC.

**Edit 2 :** I suppose that, this have to run correctly
but my PC have a problem

Comment: It's doing exactly what you're asking it to -- treating content as literal rather than markup is **exactly what CDATA is for**. Why would you expect behavior to be anything different?

Comment: If you want the `<a href="#">` to be markup, just leave off the CDATA section: `<key><a href="#">Link</a></key>`

Comment: One might ask, then, _why_ you're using a CDATA section at all in this case, since its behavior is not what you want.

Comment: Here is an example : http://hqtunes.com/hqtunes.xml 
All HTML tags are seen at my PC. It seems there is a problem at my PC and this was working, before. How can I correct this again ?

Comment: If I leave off CDATA and use directly the <a href="#"> , then the link not shown on my pc. Its written just like a plain text.

Comment: So -- in the example, they're including tags in literal text because -- presumably -- the data is going to be literally substituted into a HTML document. Which is sloppy behavior -- the Right Thing would be to use XML namespaces for HTML being embedded inside the XML document -- but then, no accounting for taste.

Comment: (string concatenation to build structured data is... well, let's say "not a best practice" and leave it at that. Still, if it's what the software consuming this document does, well, there you are).

Comment: OTOH, if _you're_ the author of the software consuming this document, you're Doing It Wrong. Use XML namespaces for embedded (X)HTML content; CDATA has no place in this kind of use case.